If generic fiber of fibered surface is geometrically connected then the same holds for closed fiber (Qing Liu 8.3.6)
In Qing Liu's book there is statement

I'm stuck in the proof of (b).

I don't understand why map $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is bijective. The proof says it follows from Proposition 3.2.7

But that is a statement about base change for varieties over fields and $\operatorname{Spec}A$ or $\operatorname{Spec} B$ are schemes which not defined over fields. I think what is correct is $B \otimes_A K(S) \cong L$, but how this implies that $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is bijective?
Here is my attempt to expend comment by Ahr. As $K(S) \subset L$ is purely inseparable for any $x \in L$ there is $n=p^m$ s.t. $x^n \in K(S)$. Taking $b \in B \subset L$ we have $n$ s.t. $b^n \in K(S)$, but $B$ is integral over $A$, and $A$ is normal hence $b^n \in A$. In particular, $1/b=b^{n-1} \otimes 1/b^n \in B \otimes K(S)=L$, so $Frac(B) \cong L$. If $I \subset B$ is an ideal, then $I=(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ and there is $n$ s.t. $x_i^n \in A$ for all $i$. Then $(\sum_i a_i x_i)^n=\sum_i a_i^n x_i^n$, so $I^n \subset A$. The map $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is injective since if $p_1, p_2 \subset B$ are primes s.t. $p_1 \cap A = p_2 \cap A$ we have $p_1^{n_1} \subseteq p_1 \cap A = p_2 \cap A \subseteq p_2$ hence $p_1 =\sqrt{p_1^{n_1}} \subseteq p_2$ and similarly $p_2 \subseteq p_1$. Finally, the map $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is surjective and open since $B$ is integral over $A$. Therefore $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a homeomorphism.

This comes from the fact $Frac(B)$ is purely inseparable over $Frac(A)$ and is equal to $B\otimes Frac(A)$ this tells you that $\text{Spec}B\to \text{Spec} A$ is injective (a certain power of a prime of $B$ is in $A$ as $A$ is normal), it is also surjective as $B/A$ is flat and finite and therefore closed an open.

Thanks. I tried to provide some details to your comment (in the post). Is that correct?

Looks good to me
